# query in codeigniter character varying

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

How can I make this right in codeigniter?

```
$this->db->query('UPDATE "table1" SET tech_voc=(select tech_voc from table1 where "tableID"='table1' AND psced_id="62") WHERE "tableID"="table1-A" AND major_id=1;');
```

I also did

```
select tech_voc from table1 where "tableID"="table1-A";     //w qoutes
select tech_voc from table1 where "tableID"=table1-A;       //w/o quotes
```

but still got error. It says

ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying. Yeah I know that

but when i try in postgreSQL

```
select tech_voc from table1 where "tableID"='table1-A'; // is correct
```

EDIT ------- @Nouphal.M
This is the ERROR message:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "`" LINE 1: UPDATE`table1` SET tech_voc= ( ^

UPDATE `table1` SET tech_voc= ( SELECT tech_voc FROM table1 WHERE `tableID`='table1' AND psced_id=62 ) WHERE `tableID`='table1-A' AND major_id=1)

EDIT ------- @tomexsans TESTING

I tried what you said and it gives server error.

Here's the code I tried for testing.

```
$sql ="SELECT tech_voc FROM table1 WHERE `tableID`= ? AND `psced_id` = ?"; 
$this->db->query($sql,array['table1','62']);
```

Comment: you should not use single or double quote for the column names but rather backticks like this, note how I use the backtick instead of single quote. `WHERE \`tableID\` = 'table1-A'`

Comment: @Prix i see. but the problem here is not the column but the data of the column which is character varying.

Comment: have you tried using the query bind method as it autmatically escapes chars. `WHERE tableID = ?`

Comment: @tomexsans can you illustrate or post a code so that I could understand properly?

Comment: $sql  ="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?"; $this->db->query($sql,[$id1,$id2]);

Comment: @tomexsans pls see my new edit post

Answer (score 0):

it's wrong in SQL:
select tech_voc from table1 where "tableID"='table1-A';

Please, try with:

```
select tech_voc from table1 where tableID='table1-A';
```

Your, final query look like :

```
    $this->db->query("UPDATE table1 SET tech_voc=(select tech_voc from table1 where 
tableID='table1' AND psced_id='62') WHERE tableID='table1-A' AND major_id=1;");
```

Comment: He forgot to remove a double quote `psced_id="'`

Comment: So, soory , now it' fine. please, check again

Comment: @vikramjain Still tableid doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is that I changed tableID to table_id in my database. PostregreSQL is case sensitive and it's hard to use it in Codeigniter.

So this is my final code looks like:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE table1 SET tech_voc=(select tech_voc from table1 where table_id='table1' AND psced_id='62') 
WHERE table_id='table1-A' AND major_id=1;");
```

Thanks for everyone who shared their idea.